# Can java JDK be portable?

Tags: java, portability

My java programs are stored in my flash drive.
I just want to know if it is possible to store the JDK in the flash drive so that I can compile and run my programs at any computer (i.e., portable).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK itself is a compiled application.  You can define JAVA_HOME to point to your JDK wherever you want, to force compilation.  However, you can't take a 64 bit JDK and run it on a 32 bit Windows machine, and likewise you can't take the Windows version and run it on Mac or Linux, so no it's not portable.

Comment: @user3408693 You can however install a bootable linux(with the JDK installed) on your flash drive and boot it on practically any machine. Then run your applications from it.